# Local Database won't show my programmaticaly added table

Tags: c#, sql, database, local, sdf

I will go at a c# contest and I will need to work with databases offline, and they  should work on every PC, so if someone copies my project and runs my program, everything will work the same.

I created a Local Database with Add - New Item and made my database.

My code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.bazalocalaConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("select * from Tabela",con);
    SqlCeDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (r.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(r["nume"].ToString());
    }
      com = new SqlCeCommand("create table taby(id int identity(1,1) primary key,nume nvarchar(10),prenume nvarchar(10) )", con);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

The problem i have is, that after I create my table, and close the program, my new table won't be there in my server explorer.. why is that?
Did i Did something wrong?

And if I work like this, will it work on every PC?

My connection string is auto generated by visual studio when I create my local database and it is

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bazalocala.sdf
```

Comment: if the query executed successfully, the table will always be there. did you hit refresh on server explorer? it may be cached

Comment: Your problem is you are adding the table programmatically in your `Form1_Load()` event handler. Add it using Server Explorer.

Comment: Please show your connectionstring. Are you using |DataDirectory| ?

Comment: My conection string is auto generated when i create the local database and it is - Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bazalocala.sdf

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is your unhandled exception handler working correctly?  Is your code hit when you set a breakpoint?  (MessageBox shown etc)

Answer (score 2):

The substitution string `|DataDirectory|` is replaced by the directory where your program runs.
During a Visual Studio debugging session this directory is BIN\DEBUG (or x86 variant).
So your table is added in a database located in BIN\DEBUG folder, while your server explorer window has a connection that points to a database located in the project folder.

You could try to add another connection that points to the database in the BIN\DEBUG folder and you will be able to see your table.

If you run your program outside VS then you don't have this problem.

To complicate further the matter there is the property `Copy to output directory` for your SDF file. If this property is set to `Copy Always`, then every time you start a debug session your SDF file is copied from your project folder to the BIN\DEBUG folder effectively overwriting the  file and the change you have made in the previous debug session. You should change this property to `Copy if Newer`

Comment: I try to add a new connection to my .sdf file from debug, i get the error 'an attempt to attach an auto named database for file C:/....failed a database with the same name exists or specified file cannot be opened

Comment: I don't understand. The code is correct. You add a new connection to the Server Explorer just to check if your table is there, it is not really needed for your code to work.

Comment: What code is correct? Anyways, i'm worried that at the contest i will go, the person who test my program will add some data to my database using F5 and when he does again everything he added programatically won't be there..

Comment: Did you read the updated answer about the Copy to Output Directory flag?

Comment: If someone else will copy my project and run the exe, he will be able to connect to the database?

Comment: Your application is composed by two parts. The Executable and its database. You need to give both parts to run the app. With DataDirectory in the connectionstring your `customer` should put the app and the database in the same folder, be sure that he has the read/write permission on that folder and your app should work. You could try it by yourself moving the exe and the sdf to a different computer and test if it works

Comment: Ah, well don't forget about the config file that contains the connectionstring and the Sql Server Compact library need to be installed on the different machine as well

Answer (score 2):

When you use |DataDirectory| and compile the program in Visual Studio, the Visual studio creates a temp database in the Debug folder which is different from your original database. That is why the added table doesn't show up in there, instead of |DataDirectory| use the actual address.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
    try
    {
        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.bazalocalaConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        //
        // The following code uses an SqlCommand based on the SqlConnection.
        //
        using (SqlCeCommandcommand = new SqlCeCommand("CREATE TABLE taby(id int identity(1,1) primary key,nume nvarchar(10),prenume nvarchar(10) );", con))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: No this is not the same. This is totally wrong. It uses a SqlConnection and a SqlCommand while you use a SqlCeConnection and SqlCeCommand. The Sql Server classes are not able to work with an SDF file

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=K:/PROJECT LOCATION/Database1.sdf");

con.Open();           
string x = "insert into TABLE(your columns) values (what values you want)";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(x, con);
try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Something is wrong","ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
}
con.Close();
```

I created a connection and gave it the full location of the database, NOT the one from the bin/debug. Then i opened the connection and wrote the string x to save that data in my database. I created a new command which i tested in a try-catch clause and finally i closed the connection.